# How to cut the long text until it fits NSTextView and also add ... in the end of cut text?

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview

How can I cut the text until it fits NSTextView? Exactly until it fits. And also then add ... in the end of this cut text?

Here is my component:

```
import PureLayout

class Card: NSCollectionViewItem {
    let textView = NSTextView()

    var card: (text: String)? {
        didSet {
            guard isViewLoaded else { return }

            if let text = card?.text {
                textView.string = text
            } else {
                textView.string = ""
            }
        }
    }

    func configureTextView() {
        textView.font = NSFont(name: "SF Pro Display", size: 12)
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isFieldEditor = false

        textView.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .top, withInset: 10)
        textView.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .right, withInset: 10)
        textView.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .bottom, withInset: 10)
        textView.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .left, withInset: 10)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()

        view.layer?.borderWidth = 1
        view.layer?.borderColor = .black

        view.addSubview(textView)

        configureTextView()
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the entry text:

[image]

Here is how it should look like in the NSTextView after it was cut:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textView.textContainer!.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail` for that. You may have to give `NSTextView` a text container into `init(frame:textContainer:)` for that.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslinebreakmode

Comment: Question is for macOS. UIKit is for iOS.

Comment: @adev Right. One can use `NSTextContainer` together with `NSLineBreakMode` on MacOS.

Comment: Your comment is correct, but your answer still has documentation pointing to `UIKit`. I am not sure how that is relevant to this question. You should probably add comment to your answer. Just saying.

Comment: @adev It‘s the swift url, the appkit-version shows objc.. If you can show me the url you would use instead I‘ll change it,

Comment: @Fabian Could you, please, show an example of how to use it? I'm a newbie in swift and I cannot get how to use it by reading a documentation

Comment: @MaksimGorodov I added how you may use it but I haven‘t tried it myself.

Comment: @Fabian seems like that's how it should be used, yea. But it doesn't work :( I tried to use all options from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslinebreakmode) but none of them changed anything. I also tried to print `textView.textContainer` and it exists

Comment: @MaksimGorodov What does limit the size of the `NSTextView`? It has an intrinsic content size based on what you assign the text view. Which moves up the levels with every constraint if the size is not constraint to a certain number, making the whole window bigger instead of cutting of the text. On iOS where all apps are fullscreen this is no issue, since the window cannot get bigger than fullscreen-limiting the text view size. On MacOS there is no such automatic size constraint.

Comment: @Fabian hm, I don't add a limit size to `NSTextView`, as you can see in the code above, I use only auto layout using PureLayout

Comment: @Fabian okay, I found out how to use it but it displays weird right now. [Here](http://prntscr.com/kvs987) is a screenshot **without** `lineBreakMode`, [here](http://prntscr.com/kvs8b7) is a screenshot **with** `lineBreakMode`. [Here](https://gist.github.com/SilencerWeb/8df8cf3ad001dc1ed29e60678d1d58eb) is a gist of this code.

Comment: @MaksimGorodov My best guess is that with paragraph style you set it truncates on each paragraph if it would continue in the next paragraph. You can try https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextcontainer/1444519-linebreakmode -> `textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode` instead of the paragraph style since that possibly truncates only the last line inside the container(which hopefully means the last visible), that may look better.

Comment: @Fabian but it doesn't work, the text just clips like without `lineBreakeMode` :( http://prntscr.com/kvv8iw. I used it like this: ` textView.textContainer?.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail`

Comment: @MaksimGorodov then I‘m out of ideas too.